# How to find out the image source used in a background image data?

Tags: css, base64, background-image, data-uri

I found out on a website an image which I like very much but when I inspected the source code with firebug i found out that it was not an image, but a div with the following CSS condition:

```
background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhJQAFAJECAMwAM7C2uP///wAAACH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh/wtYTVAgRGF0YVhNUDw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMC1jMDYwIDYxLjEzNDc3NywgMjAxMC8wMi8xMi0xNzozMjowMCAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3Lnc...");
```

Is there any way to find out the path to that image?

Comment: No, because there's no path to that image. the image data has been embedded directly into the document: http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That IS the path (sort of). Just copy the "data:image/gif..... "-part and paste into your browser, and the browser will render it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The image is embedded so if you want that image the better option is, directly save that image through that website.